# Listing members search with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am searching for an existing customer from the database. 
How can I use the results using ajax?

I want to do Listing among those with the name sought.

**jquery code**

```
    $("#txtMusteri, #txtGsmNo").keyup(function(){
    var tusKodu = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(tusKodu == '13'){
        var Arama = $(this).val();
        if($(this).attr("id") == "txtGsmNo"){
            Arama = parseInt(Arama.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''), 10);
        }
        $.post("", {formName : "KayitAra", Anahtar : $("#anahtar").val(), Text : Arama}, function(result){
            $("#test").html(result);
        });
    }
});
```

**post php file :**

```
if (post('formName') == 'KayitAra' && post('Anahtar') == md5($_SESSION['user_name'])){
$Text = post('Text');
if(is_numeric($Text)){
    $query = $db->from('servis_musteri')
    ->where('mus_gsmtel', $Text, 'LIKE')
    ->all();
    if ($query){
      foreach($query as $row){
        print_r($row);
      }
    }
}else{
    $query = $db->from('servis_musteri')
    ->where('mus_adsoyad', $Text, 'LIKE')
    ->all();
    if ( $query ){
      foreach ( $query as $row ){
        print_r($row);
      }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `post` should be `$_POST`

Comment: post function in my article. There are security measures in it :)